# OpenCV for Android: Sample Project ClassNotFound Exception

Tags: android, opencv, classnotfoundexception

I'm trying to run a sample from opencv for android. It's not working.

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
ComponentInfo{org.opencv.samples.puzzle15/org.opencv.samples.
puzzle15.Puzzle15Activity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
"org.opencv.samples.puzzle15.Puzzle15Activity" on path:
DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.opencv.samples.puzzle15-
 1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=
[/data/app-lib/org.opencv.samples.puzzle15-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

What does it mean, and how do I fix it? I would like concrete steps to fix it.

Full Log:

```
     10-25 14:03:09.794: E/AndroidRuntime(958): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     10-25 14:03:09.794: E/AndroidRuntime(958): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to     
     instantiate activity ComponentInfo{org.opencv.samples.puzzle15/
     org.opencv.samples.puzzle15.Puzzle15Activity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:      
     Didn't find class "org.opencv.samples.puzzle15.Puzzle15Activity" on path:  
     /data/app/org.opencv.samples.puzzle15-2.apk
     10-25 14:03:09.794: E/AndroidRuntime(958):     at    
     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
     10-25 14:03:09.794: E/AndroidRuntime(958):     at 
     android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
     10-25 14:03:09.794: E/AndroidRuntime(958):     at   
     android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
     10-25 14:03:09.794: E/AndroidRuntime(958):     at 
     android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
     10-25 14:03:09.794: E/AndroidRuntime(958):     at 
     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
     10-25 14:03:09.794: E/AndroidRuntime(958):     at 
     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
     10-25 14:03:09.794: E/AndroidRuntime(958):     at 
     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
     10-25 14:03:09.794: E/AndroidRuntime(958):     at 
     java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     10-25 14:03:09.794: E/AndroidRuntime(958):     at 
     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
     10-25 14:03:09.794: E/AndroidRuntime(958):     at     
     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
     10-25 14:03:09.794: E/AndroidRuntime(958):     at 
     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
     10-25 14:03:09.794: E/AndroidRuntime(958): dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeMethod)
     10-25 14:03:09.794: E/AndroidRuntime(958): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
     Didn't find class "org.opencv.samples.puzzle15.Puzzle15Activity" on path: 
    /data/app/org.opencv.samples.puzzle15-2.apk
    10-25 14:03:09.794: E/AndroidRuntime(958):  at 
    dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
    10-25 14:03:09.794: E/AndroidRuntime(958):  at 
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
    10-25 14:03:09.794: E/AndroidRuntime(958):  at 
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
    10-25 14:03:09.794: E/AndroidRuntime(958):  at 
    android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
    10-25 14:03:09.794: E/AndroidRuntime(958):  at 
    android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
```

Comment: Look [there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17273328/2099287)

Comment: @McBodik That doesn't solve anything.

Comment: Have you added reference to opencv library properly? Refer the steps shown in this blog http://opencvstart.blogspot.in/2013/03/first-of-all-you-need-jdk-installed-on.html

Comment: Yes, I've added a reference to opencv library. I did everything in that blog post. It builds but immediately crashes (see log in my post)

Comment: I think its some problem with the java compiler..Try this..Change your java compiler..Right click on your project -> Properties ->Java Compiler -> Tick Enable project specific settings -> select compiler compliance level as `1.6`

Comment: @AbhishekV I appreciate the help. But I already have these settings.

Comment: You may have extracted example into wrong source directory. So under src it doesn't look like org/opencv/samples/puzzle15.

Comment: put please Android.mk, Puzzle15Activity and Manifest

Comment: Here are the Solution:
[Initialize OPENCV][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18103994/convert-android-bitmap-to-opencv-mat-and-backwards/24381565#24381565

Answer (score 0):

After Importing from this [OpenCV for android](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html) and download [ADT Bundle](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

**Instead of this :**

```
   Warning : After the initial import, on a non-Windows (Linux and Mac OS) operating system Eclipse will still show build errors for applications with native C++ code. To resolve the issues, please do the following:
Open Project Properties -> C/C++ Build, and replace “Build command” text to "${NDKROOT}/ndk-build" (remove .cmd at the end).
```

**try following steps:**

Download the ndk build [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html)

**Specify the NDK location:**

Windows >>> preferences >> Android >> NDK >> Set the location of the NDK  (which u have downloaded from the above link)

**Get location of the project :**

Right Click on the project >>> properties >> resource >> location

Eg : Location : D:\OpenCV-2.4.6-android-sdk-r2\OpenCV-2.4.6-android-sdk\samples\15-puzzle

**Build the project using cmd:**

D:\OpenCV-2.4.6-android-sdk-r2\OpenCV-2.4.6-android-sdk\samples\15-puzzle>D:\android-ndk-r9\ndk-build

D:\android-ndk-r9\ndk-build(Your NDK path)

Note: Make sure u have included the library project and installed OpenCV Manager