# Android NDK. No C/C++ section in Eclipse project properties

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, opencv, android-ndk

I am trying to follow the instructions specified [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html) to install OpenCV for Wlipse.

The instructions state:

Open Project Properties -> C/C++ Build, and replace “Build command” text to "${NDKROOT}/ndk-build"

However, if I open my Project Properties I have no C/C++ section.

I am using Android SDK ADT Bundle for OSX

I have downloaded the NDK

I have set the NDK location under ADT->Properties->Android->NDK

I have validated that the Android Native Dev Tools and C/C++ Dev Tools are installed

I have imported the project correctly

Why don't I have a C/C++ section under Project->Properties

**Next problem.**

Ok I have found how to add the c/c++ build command thanks to srikanth gr

Now when i try and build the OpenCV Library I get the following error

OpenCV.mk: No such file or directory

the current reference in the jni/Android.mk is

include OpenCV.mk

I did a search on my system and no OpenCV.mk file exists. There is a OpenCV.mk.in. Do i need to build that to create the OpenCV.mk? If so how?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your description lacks right click on project, "Android Tools" -> "Add NativeSupport..."

Comment: Thank you that helped a lot. Any chance you could have a look at my new question.

Comment: It costs nothing to start a new question, or to accept an answer. But if you keep questions mixed, nobody else can reuse your experience,  which has been the principal idea of SO. Please undo your edit and open a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

I have already answered here check the steps to setup NDK [Android NDK and OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19555878/opencv-for-android-sample-project-classnotfound-exception/19676118#19676118) 
[Android-NDK](http://deadmango.com/index.php/archives/1872)